# How do i pass data from an HTML on one page to a Javascript on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want to have a text box where the user fills in a number, and then presses go.  The system goes to a different page where data is filled based upon the number that was input on the first page.  Currently I have the code:

```
<body>
<center>
<div style=" width:205px; background:#cccccc; border:1px solid black;"> 
Previous week to display.
<br>
(1=current)
<br>
<input name="week" type="text" maxlength="2" id="weekID" VALUE="1" size="1" style="text-align: center;">
<form action="Changeovers2.asp?value=2">                                
    <input type="submit" style="width: 100px; height: 30px" value="Go">
</form>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Table"></div>
<br>
<form action="Index.asp">           
    <input type="submit" value="Index">
</form>
</center>
</body>
```

Problem 1: When I implement this code, for whatever reason the URL doesn't add the ?value=2 on the end.

Problem 2: How can I get the number that is being input in the text box into the end of that url (In place of the 2 in ?value=2)

Problem 3:  How can I take the data out of the URL into javascript.  I cannot seem to find out how to do this.  When I Google, I seem to find tons of different ways to get this data into other forms, but not javascript.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You should try putting the value of "value2" into a hidden field in your form.  Then it would get submitted with the rest of the form with no need to try appending it.

Comment: Google session variables for javascript.

Comment: Did you even look at the bazillion existing answers? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+pass+value+from+one+page+to+another

Comment: You'd be better off using PHP to send the form data to another page which constructs the data using the user input.

Comment: Thanks durbnpoisn and nFinlt.  With your answers, I was able to search the appropriate pages I needed to fix my problems.